HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start in NopCommerce 4.70.0
Im struggling to fix this problem, I tried many things still I didnt have success. Im trying to Upgrade from Nopcommerce 4.60.0 to 4.70.0. Any suggestions how to fix this problem. Im using localhost/Windows/IIS/Visual Studio. Im getting the below error. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start
Common solutions to this issue:
The app failed to start
The app started but then stopped
The app started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more guidance on diagnosing and handling these errors, visit Troubleshoot ASP.NET 
Core on Azure App Service and IIS.


I think you forget to install Hosting bundle for IIS. Download from  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-8.0.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer and for visual studio https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-8.0.204-windows-x64-installer download this
